# Cursor lost in highlighted text - Vim

Tags: macos, vim, vi

When text is highlighted in vim, for example using the 'em' tag when writing a HTML document, I find that in some color schemes the cursor becomes invisible, making it difficult to correctly place the closing tag. Is there a way to have the cursor change color over highlighted text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem led me down quite a rabbit hole and caused me to learn a lot more about how syntax highlighting works than intended.

I learned that the reason my, supposedly italic, text was highlighted in the first place, is because the Mac terminal doesn't support italics ("[Enabling italics in vim syntax highlighting for mac terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326998/enabling-italics-in-vim-syntax-highlighting-for-mac-terminal)")

I realised, thanks to "[Colour colour everywhere! 256 colour-mode for Linux consoles](http://www.robmeerman.co.uk/unix/256colours)", that due to the color profile I had chosen in Terminal's preferences, my "bright" and "normal" colors showed no difference, and for that reason my color profiles never looked like the screenshots.

And, finally, I solved my cursor getting lost problem by changing the cursor color in the Terminal preferences.

Comment: Now that you got it working with Terminal, look into using [iTerm2](http://iterm2.com/). It's like Terminal done right.

Comment: I did download iTerm2 when I was trying to get italics to display but after figuring out a decent work around with terminal I felt that I wasn't really going to make the most of iTerm2's differences with my normal terminal use. I still have it there for the future if I ever advance to command line ninja black belt level. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

[Change color of cursor in gvim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158860/change-color-of-cursor-in-vim)

Look at both answers sir, I think you'll have your answer in there....

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to hook into the `CursorMoved,CursorMovedI` events and then determine the highlight group under the cursor with `synIDattr(synIDtrans(synID(line("."), col("."), 1)), "name")`. If it's one of those diffcult-to-see groups, you can issue a `:highlight Cursor ...` command to change it (or else change it back).

But this is rather complicated. Why don't you simply modify the colorscheme and choose a color that is easily recognized under all circumstances?! (The `:hi` command lists all colors and helps you choose one.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip about using :hi command. It's been very useful in customizing my syntax highlighting colors.